# Using paper_trail with a class whose primary key is not 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I've used paper_trail for a couple of models in my rails 3 app but
I've hit a snag when trying to apply it to a join model - its
primary key is not id.

I checked the doc and the source but couldn't see any options to
override the use of id. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is just to add a method, id, that references the primary key.
Once paper_trail has that it's happy.

Comment: How do you do that?